# Cannot debug T4 template in VS2017

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, t4

In VS2017 Community, I cannot debug T4 Templates, which works in 2015.

I have a very basic template, such as this...

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#
var a = "Hello";
var b = "World";
#>
<#=($"{a} {b}!")#>
```

`Run Custom Tool` and `Transform All T4 Templates` both options work, and text file contains expected output

> Hello World!

If I put breakpoint somewhere and use `Debug T4 Template` from the context menu of .tt, it throws this error

> Unable to start transformation run creation process.

However it works fine in VS 2015, and I'm able to debug there.

What I could be missing? how to debug T4 Templates in VS 2017? Note that I don't have any Tool/ Extension installed in VS2015 to debug T4

Comment: Fixed in an upcoming release.  See comment from Ariel Vang.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/46721/unable-to-debug-t4-text-template-in-vs2017.html

Answer (score 9):

I have had the same issue, I don't know why it doesn't work this way but I have a work around.

Set debug to true, and add the diagnostic namespace

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
```

In your T4 template write

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

Then run your template (easiest way it just to save it) and it will ask if you would like to debug in a new instance of visual studio.

Comment: Thanks @Rezonir, debugger shows up if I do what you have mentioned, but its inconvenient and doesn't work nicely with my real project where i need to put conditional breakpoints and watch few variables.

Comment: To mention that "Debugger.Launch();" need to be inside of one of your T4 template "<# Debugger.Launch(); #>" nodes.

Comment: A video of it working here.
https://youtu.be/U2NzQqghu_A

Once in a while it will say `The debugger you selected cannot be started.  Would you like to choose another?`  Say yes and you'll be prompted to use Visual Studio again and it should work on the second try.  I have  found that it won't do this again until you restart Visual Studio.

Comment: This did not work for me, unfortunately i just had to use vs.net 2015 to get debugging support.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to just add these two lines to the top of your T4 template.

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<# System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); #>
```

Then just run the template by saving the file and visual studio will prompt you to debug in a new instance.

If you use Host in your template and you get the error `The name 'Host' does not exist in the current context` then set `hostspecific="true"'.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Visual Studio 2022. As it turned out, I needed to install Text Templating Transformations in the individual components section of the Visual Studio installer. I figured this out from [this note in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp&source=docs)

> The Text Template Transformation component is automatically installed
> as part of the Visual Studio extension development workload. You can
> also install it from the Individual components tab of Visual Studio
> Installer, under the SDKs, libraries, and frameworks category. Install
> the Modeling SDK component from the Individual components tab.

[image: Visual Studio Installer - Individual components tab]